# Serializing an EnumerableRowCollection into a JSONResult

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I have the following method which is supposed to return a JSONResult so I can use it in an AJAX method with javascript and load autocomplete suggestions for a textbox. I will load this everytime a particular dropdown list changes.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post), Authorize]
    private JsonResult GetSchemaNodeValues(string SchemaNodeId)
    {
        var query = @"Select ld.""Value"" 
        From ""LookupData"" ld, ""SchemaNode"" sn
        Where sn.""LookupTypeId"" = ld.""LookupTypeId""
        And sn.""SchemaNodeId"" = '{0}'";

        DataSet data = new DataSet();


            data = ServiceManager.GenericService.ExecuteQuery(String.Format(query, SchemaNodeId)).Data;

        var res = data.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dr => new
        {
            Value = dr["Value"].ToString()
        });

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);

    }
```

I get the following error under `return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);`

```
Error   106 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult'
```

Is there any way to get past this?

Before this I tried using System.Web.mvc.Controller.Json(res); which returns a JSONResult from an object.

But I couldn't use it because my class is a PageDialog not a Controller so it doesn't have access to Controller's protected internal methods like JSon(). The error I got was that JSon() is inaccessible due to its protection level. The Controller class was locked and I can't make it public or create a workaround so I changed the approach using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);

Any suggestions would be extremely welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private dynamic GetSchemaNodeValues(string SchemaNodeId)
{
    ...
    return data.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dr => new
    {
        Value = dr["Value"].ToString()
    });
}
```

or

```
private string GetSchemaNodeValues(string SchemaNodeId)
{
    ...
    var result = data.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dr => new
    {
        Value = dr["Value"].ToString()
    });
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

Comment: If you check my description I already tried using Json(res). The full path is System.Web.mvc.Controller.Json(res); It won't let me use it. Please read my description to see the reason so I wont repeat! Thx for your quick response though!

Comment: not according to the code you posted. the method returns a JsonResult but you are returning a string is the method body. that is where the error is coming from. in my code sampe. the method returns an ActionResult and the body of the method passes the anonymous type to the Json method.

Comment: You're right on the first part. The problem is indeed that I return a string when the method needs a JSONResult. But the problem is not the string. It's how to convert that string into a JSONResult. 
Like I said I can't use return Json(res); 
I get an error saying Json() does not exist in the current context.
Then even if I change it to System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Json(res); it recognizes it but gives me the other error that I said: JSon() is inaccessible due to its protection level. So in other words I can't use JSon(res)

Comment: you're controller action is inheriting from the `Controller` base class correct? and you are calling the controller from either the url or redirecting from another action, correct? What you describe sounds like either the action is not properly called or the usage is incorrect.

Comment: OK, in that case change the method signature to return a string or the anonymous object, not a JsonResult. JsonResult (and controller) are specific to ASP.NET MVC. They do not make sense outside of HTTP. i'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I ended up creating another cs file (a controller basically) containing only this method so I could use the Json() function. But your answer is what helped me clearing things out so I accept it and thank you very much :)