# WCF POST Params not returning in JSON format

Tags: c#, json, wcf, azure

I am developing an android application and am trying to send data through a webservice.
For some reason my WCF is not sending data in JSON format, I have set bindings to webHttpBinding, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json

Here is my Code for IService:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "LoginMobile",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    LoginCredentials GetLogin(LoginCredentials Lc);

[DataContract]
public class LoginCredentials
{
    [DataMember(Name = "AccountID")]
    public string AccountID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "NRIC")]
    public string NRIC
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And my Service:

```
    public LoginCredentials GetLogin(LoginCredentials credentials)
    {
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PCSDB"].ConnectionString;
        string strCommandText = "Select AccountID from Account Where NRIC=@NRIC AND Password=@Password";

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, sqlConnection))
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRIC", credentials.NRIC);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", credentials.Password);

                int queryResult = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    credentials.AccountID = reader["AccountID"].ToString();
                    return credentials;
                }
                else
                {
                    credentials.AccountID = "0";
                    return credentials;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me! Have been on this the whole day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code. Your method defintion is correct and returns json as expected.

As far as I can see, the only way for your method  to return an XML is if your method throws an exception. (you can test it by adding `return credentials` as the first line to your method)

You can override this behaviour(returning an xml when an exception is thrown) by writing a custom error handler as below.

Just add `[JsonErrorHandlerBehavior]` to your class after `[ServiceContract]` attribute

```
public class JsonErrorHandlerBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IErrorHandler, IServiceBehavior
{
    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        //Log the error
        return true;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        var fd = new JsonFaultDetail();
        fd.Message = error.Message;

        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, string.Empty, fd, new DataContractJsonSerializer(fd.GetType()));

        var jsonFormatting = new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json);
        fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, jsonFormatting);

        var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessageProperty()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
        };

        fault.Properties.Add(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, httpResponse);
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher dispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            if (dispatcher.BindingName.Contains("WebHttpBinding"))
                dispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(this);
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }
}
```

**BTW,** the json string you post to service should be like

`{"Lc":{"AccountID":null,"NRIC":"nric1","Password":"password1"}}`  as defined in interface,

**not** `{"LoginCredentials":{"AccountID":null,"NRIC":"nric1","Password":"password1"}}`

Otherwise this would result in `credentials` parameter being null and `credentials.NRIC` would throw an exception

Comment: ohh my god, I cannot believe i got stucked the whole day because i was sending in LoginCredentials.. you just saved another day of my life! thanks alot !

Answer (score 0):

When I worked with JSon, I used something like this on my WebMethod.

```
//references. //
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Web.Script.Services;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

// returning. //
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials);
```

and on my client side I used:-

```
// client side reference. //
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

// storing returned data. //
    var jsondata = $.parseJSON(data.d);
    credentials = jsondata.credentials;
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. Need more explanation.

Comment: I dont have JsonConvert in my library :X

Comment: trying to find it now, do you happen to know where i can get it?

Comment: Im getting "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to my LoginCredentials" on return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials);

Comment: No need to manually serialize the returned object to Json. WCF *should* to it automatically.

Comment: But my return credentials crashes my android application with org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: 'Cannot implicitly convert error' - Read about it - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588703/serializing-an-enumerablerowcollection-into-a-jsonresult

It shows how to solve the error.